# pycharm and Linux showing different errors while importing modules from different directories

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

```
main_project
├── base_dir
│   └── helper
│       └── file_helper.py
│       └── __init__.py
    └── jobs
        └── adhoc_job.py
        └── __init__.py
```

Below are the contents of `file_helper.py`

```
import os


# source and target table
def table_names(script_name):
    """
    :param script_name: name of the script without .py extension
    :return: src_table, tgt_table
    """
    src_table = os.environ[script_name + '_src_tbl']
    tgt_table = os.environ[script_name + '_tgt_tbl']
    return src_table, tgt_table
```

Below are the contents of `adhoc_job.py`

```
import sys
import os


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR))
from helper.file_helper import *  # noqa: E402

# Find script name and remove .py extension
script_name = os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0]

# Invoke table_names function
src_tbl_name, target_table = table_names(script_name)

print(20 * '*' + 'Source Table is ' + src_tbl_name + 20 * '*')
print(20 * '*' + 'Target Table is ' + target_table + 20 * '*')
```

Now this scripts runs abosultely fine in a `Linux` box

But If I have this code in `pycharm` it is showing `Unresolved reference 'helper'` error

Changes attempted in `pycharm`

```
1) from base_dir.helper.file_helper import *  # noqa: E402
```

The above is throwing `No module named base_dir` error in `Linux`

```
2) from ..helper.file_helper import *  # noqa: E402
```

The above is throwing `attempted relative import beyond top-level package` error in `Linux`

I tried to add `__init__.py` files at `base_dir` and `main_project` directory level but still I am getting the above errors.

What I want is I should not have any `import module` errors both in `Linux` and `pycharm`

What should I do to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyCharm default source path (used for all the warnings, and as the default for all run configurations) is the top level project path. This doesn't match with what you have, and we get these warnings since no paths are matching up anymore.

You can either go through the project structure settings and tweak this:
`File -> Settings -> Project Structure`

or you can right click the `base_dir` directory in the project explorer and select:
`Mark Directory as -> Sources Root`